# Hypothetical - Support for Non-ASCII characters in non-string text

Tags: java, compiler-construction, programming-languages, ascii, portability

Say, for example, that in Java version 9, someone wanted to add support for the ≤ and ≥ characters as operands, which would work exactly like the <= and >= operands, respectively. Would this be possible, since ≤ and ≥ are non-ASCII characters/not part of the standard charset, without destroying portability? Would it be feasible? Do any major programming languages have support for something like this?

Comment: Can't you already use unicode in Java source code?

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't allow operator overloading, and since that's a pretty fundamental principle of the language I don't think you'd ever be able to use ≤ or ≥ for <= or >=.

However, Scala (another JVM language) supports both operator overloading *and* using Unicode characters as identifiers. Here's a sample REPL session where I define `≤` and `≥` operators for numeric types:

```
scala> implicit class ExtendedNumeric[T](n: T)(implicit numeric: Numeric[T]) {
     | import numeric._
     | def `≥`(other: T) = n >= other
     | def `≤`(other: T) = n <= other
     | }
defined class ExtendedNumeric

scala> 1 ≤ 2
res0: Boolean = true

scala> 5 ≤ -5
res1: Boolean = false

scala> 8.0 ≥ 0.0001
res2: Boolean = true
```

Comment: I didn't mean operator overloading in the sense that the programmer defines a new operator), I meant that they would actually add it to the compiler in Java 8, much as they are adding support for lambda expressions. Would that be possible? If it is, then does any language already have "inherent" support for ≤ and ≥ - in the sense that you don't have to define them before using them like you did in your example?

Comment: Edit: I just found out that apparently ALGOL supports ≤ and ≥, as well as ÷ and several other special characters. If such an old language supports them, why don't most modern ones?

Comment: @user1126849 - [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_syntax_and_symbols), another very old language (1964), also supports ≤ and ≥ as operators. In my opinion, the reason that most modern programming languages don't support them is because it's hard to type non-ASCII characters on a standard keyboard. (It's easy to type ≤ & ≥ on OSX—but not as easy on Linux or Windows by default.)

Comment: @user1126849 - As for your question about compiler support, yes, the Java team could add support for ≤ and ≥ into the compiler, probably with very little work. Since they already support unicode, all they would have to do is add ≤ and ≥ to their tokenizer, and have them map to the same tokens as <= and >=.

Comment: I think it was because the era of ALGOL and APL was an era of early experimentation.  Everything computer-related was expensive, so the costs of supporting non-ASCII characters were swamped by other costs.  Once computers were commoditized (even to the degree of minicomputers), issues like support of nonstandard character sets and custom keyboards became relatively more important.  (note that Unicode wasn't even conceived until ~1987...)

Answer (score 1):

Java already supports non-ascii characters. For instance, the following program compiles just fine:

```
public class Test {

    public static final float π = 3.1415927f; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(π);
    }

}
```

(Of course, you'll need to use a source file character encoding that contains π)

However, since ≤ and ≥ may not be used in identifiers, introducing them as operators would not break backwards compatibility.

Numerous languages support defining your own operators. After all, the only thing that distinguishes an operator from a function call is the infix notation, i.e. that the operator name appears between rather than before its operands. For an (incomplete) list of such languages, see the wikipedia article on [operator overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading).

Comment: Wait, I thought variable names had to start with a letter, dollar sign, or underscore?

Comment: π is a letter in the greek alphabet.

Comment: Yes, but I originally thought that only a-z and A-Z counted as 'letters' for this purpose. Are all greek letters allowed?

Comment: The Java Language Specification [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8): "Letters and digits may be drawn from the entire Unicode character set, which supports most writing scripts in use in the world today, including the large sets for Chinese, Japanese, and Korean. This allows programmers to use identifiers in their programs that are written in their native languages."